# ctags match if not comment

Tags: regex, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

In the plugin tagbar the author recomends adding some lines to the file `.ctags` for generating some nice latex tags. One example is

```
--regex-latex=/^\\section[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\. \1/s,section/
```

the only problem I have with this is that it would match a line with a comment. A comment in latex is any line is whatever follows a `%`. So I tried to modify the regular expression to:

```
--regex-latex=/^[[:space:]]*[^%]+\\section[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\. \2/s,section/
```

The part that I added `[[:space:]]*[^%]+` just tries eliminate the lines that have one or more space followed by the `%` char.
But now the problem is that a line starting with `\section{whatever}` will not generate any tags. Is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out and it is easier than I thought:

```
--regex-latex=/^[[:space:]]*[^%]+\\section[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\. \2/s,section/
```

should simply be

```
--regex-latex=/^[[:space:]]*[^%]*\\section[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\. \2/s,section/
```

So instead of `[^%]+`, I changed it to `[^%]*`.
I don't think I understand why, but it seems to work.